# In Azure Logic Apps, How to make a HTTP Get/Post Call with NTLM Authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, http-authentication

I am trying to make a HTTP (Get/Post) call in Azure Logic Apps ?
The called service is on-premise (it's in fact a webservice) and it supports NTLM Authentication.

I can reach the service via postman (enabling NTLM Authentication).
Does Azure Logic Apps support it ?
if not, What are the alternatives..

Thanks
Prabath

Comment: Our Findings so far: Azure Logic App doesn't support NTLM authentication... We run LA's in ISE: While looking at the IIS logs of web service, we noticed that the IP Address is provided in place of User account.. We think of alternative workaround in our case.... Since the end system is not willing to provide alternative way of authentication, we plan to build an on-prem API (wrapper around web service) and call that in LA..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logic app doesn't support NTLM authentication

Answer (score 0):

With a little "hack" you can actually execute a REST API call in Logic Apps with NTLM authentication.
You can use the following action: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepoint/#send-an-http-request-to-sharepoint
When you create the API connection you can check 'use on-premise gateway' and then use Windows authentication.
You can execute GET/PUT/POST/PATCH/DELETE and set custom headers